# How to call method with object from another perl file

Tags: perl

I know how to use static method (it works on hello worlds):

```
require $pathToFile;
{
no strict 'refs';
&{$methodName}();
}
```

But it's doesn't work on another, more complicated methods, I have error like:

> Undefined subroutine &FunctionRunner::funcTest called at (...)

I tried something like:

```
require $pathToFile;
{
no strict 'refs';
$pathToFile->{$methodName}->();
}
```

And none of the functions works:

> Undefined subroutine &main:: called at (...)

1. Why main when I wanted use $methodName from $pathToFile file??

I found calls this methods with eval, so I tried:

```
my $testResult = eval { $pathToFile->{$methodName}->() };
```

or

```
{
no strict 'refs';
my $method = $pathToFile->{$methodName};
my $testResult = eval( "main::$method()" );
}
```

and both tries didn't have errors, but just didn't do something. 
Script ended, and method didn't call.

2. Why this doesn't work and how can I call method from another script in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you have a method that works (in your first example) then why do you need an alternative approach?

Comment: Sorry, this works only for a static methods and thats was a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` will add .pm to bareword, but if you are using variable, you must do something like this `require "$x.pm"; $x->foo()`. Read more in `perldoc -f require`

p.pl:

```
use lib './';

my $x = 'P';

require "$x.pm";
my $y = 'foo';

$x->$y();
```

P.pm:

```
package P;

sub foo {
    print 'HELLO FROM foo()!';
}

1
```

Comment: Thanks,
that means I have to call method from .pl file, but it's work too.